# is-valid icon overlap with drowdown select icon Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When class "is-valid" is applied to a downdown menu `<select>`, the is-valid check symbol and dropdown arrow partially overlap in Chrome. How can i position the is-valid symbol further to the left?

https://www.codeply.com/p/uLwylBYZTy

Comment: you need to change background-position is right, just change in left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.form-control.is-valid, .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    border-color: #28a745;
    padding-left: calc(1.5em + .75rem);
   
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%2328a745' d='M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left calc(.375em + .1875rem);
    background-size: calc(.75em + .375rem) calc(.75em + .375rem);
}
```

Comment: Apart from not wanting to move the icon all the way over to the left i was still able to tweak your answer according to my needs. Thanks!

Comment: Put some event for your needs to add .is-valid  may be you need invalid class .. icon too.Please explain what exactly what you need..

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `.custom-select` class to the `<select>` element like on the [Bootstrap examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#supported-elements):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container py-2">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <label for="x-select" class="col-2 col-form-label pr-0">Type</label>
         <select id="x-select" class="col-10 form-control form-control-sm custom-select is-valid ">
            <option disabled selected>Select me</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```